# Ignore updating missing fields with Confluent JDBC Connector

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Say I have a Postgres database table with the fields "id", "flavor" and "item". I also have a Kafka topic with two messages (let's ignore the kafka-key and assume the ID is in the value for now. Schema-definition is also omitted):

```
{"id": 1, "flavor": "chocolate"} 

{"id": 1, "item": "cookie"}
```

Now I'd like to use the Confluent JDBC (Sink) Connector for persisting the kafka messages in UPSERT-mode, hoping to get to the following end result in the database:

```
id | flavor    | item
----------------------
1  | chocolate | cookie
```

Ẁhat I *did* get, however, is was this:

```
id | flavor    | item
----------------------
1  | null      | cookie
```

I assume that's because the second message uses an UPDATE-statement where it infers the "null" values for fields that weren't provided, and writes those null-values over my actual data.

Is there a way to get to my desired result by changing the configuration of either the Confluent JDBC Connector or PostgreSQL 12? Failing that, is there another reasonably supported postgreSQL compatible connector out there that can do this?

---

Here's my connector configuration (connection details obviously redacted):

```
{
    "name": "sink-jdbc-upsertstest",
        "config": {
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
            "tasks.max": "1",
            "topics": "TEST-upserts",           
                        
            "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database",
            "connection.user": "user",
            "connection.password": "password",
            
            "dialect.name": "ExtendedPostgreSqlDatabaseDialect",
            "table.name.format": "upsert-test",
            
            "batch.size": "100",
            "insert.mode": "upsert",
            "auto.evolve": "true",
            "auto.create": "true",
            "pk.mode": "record_value",
            "pk.fields": "id",
                        
            "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
            
            "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
            "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
            
            "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "dlq_upserts",
            "errors.tolerance": "all",          
            "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": "1",
            "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true"
        }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're hoping it'll parse out individual fields for the UPDATE query? And ignore nulls? Can you share your full connector config?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Exactly. Apparently, the connector uses a statement like "INSERT .. ON CONFLICT .. DO UPDATE SET .. " when using upsert-mode with postgres. I was hoping to have some means of excluding fields that are not in the Kafka-Message from that SET statement somehow. Ah, and I added the connector configuration above.

Comment: I think this feature makes sense, but surprised didn't find any configuration for it, or Github issue that seems to ask for the same thing. I guess my only concern is what would happen on `{"id": 1}` records? Nothing? Have you tried using update mode instead of upsert? Or not since you do want to add new ID rows

Comment: @OneCricketeer: I've since opened an Issue on Github, so maybe something can be done about it. As far as I understand update mode wouldn't help in my case, as I want to create new rows quite often. The idea actually was to "build" a new row out of incoming data segments, so the intial INSERT is quite importanat. Maybe I'm abusing the system and there's a better way e.g. using a compacted topic and only then persisting the finished message. I'm not sure if I wouldn't run into the exact same problem there, however.

Comment: By default, a compacted topic would have the same behavior; new records of the same key overwrite old ones. The alternative is to use a KTable and have your own logic that merges incoming records into existing ones

Comment: That's what I feared. This whole thing was a small scale test to see if I somehow get around having to build a KTable :/ Looks like I'll have to do it anyway.